# Jetpack could not contact wordpress

Tags: errors, plugin-jetpack

I recently created a site and installed [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me) and activated it, but it gives me the following error:

> Jetpack could not contact WordPress.com: register_http_request_failed. This usually means something is incorrectly configured on your web host.
>   Failed to connect to 76.74.254.123: Permission denied

Comment: Are you inputting your WordPress.com username and password? Note: it's not asking for your self-hosted WP admin login info.

Comment: it asks to click on the button in order to connect to wordpress.com when I click it I get this error

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: activate jetpack, on the top a div appears asking to connect to wordpress.com (to enable the features), I click it and the above error appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was receiving an error similar to this on one of my past sites. [Turned out](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/jetpack-error?replies=11) that my host was blocking XML-RPC requests to remote servers. My solution: switch hosts (unless you're running on a VPS where you can configure your server).